# Why is heap overflow "allowed" to freeze the system?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory

This code takes a number as input on the command line and calls the heapOverflow() function that many times:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void heapOverflow()
{
    unsigned *some_array = malloc(50000);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned num_calls = atoi(argv[1]);

    while (num_calls > 0)
    {
        heapOverflow();
        num_calls--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On Linux Mint 17.1, running this with a large enough input (e.g. 10000000 in my case) freezes the system for a few minutes, before bash returns with "Killed", and then the system remains slow for a couple more minutes.

Why does the OS allow a process to take over memory to such a degree? Shouldn't the scheduler and memory manager work together to kill a process when it becomes clear that it will request too much heap memory? Or is there a situation in which giving all this memory to one process could be useful (i.e. could the process actually be doing useful work even while the rest of the system, or at least the X GUI system, is frozen?)

Comment: `malloc` returns `NULL` when unsuccessful. Please check, it is essential.

Comment: The Linux kernel allows memory over-commit (so that programs are allowed to request more memory than is available, and the allocations succeed, but the code crashes later when the memory isn't available after all).  Search for 'Linux OOM Killer' (out of memory killer) on your favourite search engine.  Your code doesn't really use the memory it is allocating; it takes a long time to run out because you have to run out of space for the pointers, not the memory itself.  If you zeroed the memory after allocating it (use `calloc()` perhaps), you'd crash quicker, and with less impact on your system.

Comment: What do you think should happen when a process actually needs a lot of memory? Should it be killed anyway?

Comment: @immibis Right, I guess I'm incorrectly conflating the OS and the distro software. Is the idea that the kernel doesn't need to care about the relative importance of processes, and that it "trusts" the programmer to choose how best to use the memory?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the detailed answer and the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the OS allow a process to take over memory to such a degree?

Because it is configured to do so.

The Linux kernel supports, among other features, per-process resource limits as standardized in [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html); see e.g. [`prlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/prlimit.1.html) for a command-line access to these, and [`getrlimit()/setrlimit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) for the C library interface.

In most Linux distributions, these limits are set by a Pluggable Authentication Module pam_limits in [limits.conf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/limits.conf.5.html).

The problem is, those limits are very task-specific. They vary a lot from system to system, and indeed even from user to user: some don't like their system to start paging (slow down like OP described) and would rather the process to fail; others prefer to wait for a while since they actually need the results from the resource-hungry process. Setting the limits is the responsibility of the system administrator.

I guess one could easily write a program that checks the current configuration (in particular, `/proc/meminfo`), and set the resource limits for a single-user desktop/laptop machine. However, you could just as well create a helper script, say `/usr/local/bin/run-limited`,

```
#!/bin/sh
exec prlimit --as=1073741824 --rss=262144 "$@"
```

so you can run any of your programs with address space limited to 1 GB and resident set size (amount of RAM actually used) to 256k pages.